# Fullcalendar for HTML5 LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the Full Calender jQuery plugin.

I wanted to store the events and retrieve thru LocalStorage HTML5.

And I have achieved storing part using JSON and got back the item from localstorage item by JSON Parse.

nw when I loop through the JSON value (for more then 50 values) and assign the same to the events object its not working correctly.

Here is my loop ( Sample )

```
var vEvents = '[';
    
for(i=1; i<=1; i++)
{
    vEvents += '{ "title": "new appointment", "start": "12-MAR-2012 14:00"  }';
}

vEvents += ']';
```

and it Assignin like this

```
events: vEvents,
```

Here is the console log o/p :-

```
[{ "title": "new appointment", "start": "12-MAR-2012 14:00"  }]
```

The fullcalender is not fetching the correct o/p , whereas if i put it like below ( static ) its working correctly.

```
var vEvents = [{ "title": "new appointment", "start": "12-MAR-2012 14:00"  }];
```

Kindly help me on the same please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your effort. This is how I store:

```
calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',{title: title,start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay,
                            description :'test',
                            save : localStorage.setItem("iCals"+eventIdLocal, JSON.stringify({"title": title, "start": start,"end" : end , "allDay" : allDay }))

                        }
```

and this is how I retrieve back:

```
var eventIdLocal = localStorage.getItem("getiCalsEventIdiCals");

        var title;

        valeventsiCals = '[';  

        for(i=1; i<=eventIdLocal; i++)
        {
            var numval = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("iCals"+i));

            valeventsiCals += '{"id" :"'+i+'"',
            valeventsiCals += ',"title" :"'+numval.title+'"',
            valeventsiCals += ',"start" :"'+numval.start+'"';

            if(i<eventIdLocal)
            valeventsiCals += "},";  
        }   

        valeventsiCals +='}]';
```

Comment: fixed it. events: jQuery.parseJSON(valeventsiCals) which will convert the sting to JSON Object

Comment: how to remove the msdropdown jquery option value kindly do the needful.

Comment: could share your code about how you save the events to the localstorage?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are merely appending a string, whereas fullcalendar expects an object (that is why the second case works). Before storing the data in the localStorage, simply convert it to JSON string.

```
localStorage.eventsList = JSON.stringify(vEvents);
```

And convert it back to an object when retrieving from the store

```
var events = JSON.parse(localStorage.eventsList);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your feedback... i am just doing the same thing which u mentioned.i just posted the my sample code here...before stroing it i am using the JSON.stringify and getting the back the results by JSON.parse. but still its not displaying the correct o/p when i copy and paste the same looped o/p to a new txt file and call the txt file like events : 'events.txt' i am getting the correct o/p.

Comment: I've added a simple demo based on my understanding of your need. http://jsfiddle.net/cz55S/